# how to save user edited information

Tags: content-management-system, contenteditable

I am new to coding and currently building a website.
I am struggling with a part of my project-----

The basic idea of the function is to...

1. user clicks the edit page button
2. the page enters edit mode and enables the user to add his own information in a separate side of page
3. the users presses save button and the information saves
4. the user can access the saved information when ever he/she wants to even after closing the tab.
   *the information should not be visible to other users and edited information for each should be different*
   *there is no sign in/log in page hence there has to be a separate setting to save the information for the user*

thanks,
Armaan

I have looked at other responses on overflow but am not able to find the right response as there are too many solutions

Comment: Building a whole CMS is too broad for stackoverflow. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is when the user click save button after editing, you could save the contents of the page in useState or using redux. Then you can display is as you wish by retrieving data from the state/reducer